# PyQT: Add widget after window show

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to add a button on existing GUI, dynamically.
I have connected the "Button" to "AddButton" function, I am trying to add dynamically a third button, but I can't see it on GUI.

Although, I can access it programmatically the follwing code, returns the button text!

```
print(self.ui.pushButton_3.text())
```

What I am doing wrong here?

I have this code:

```
import os

os.system("C:\Python37\python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x  beta.ui -o beta_gui.py")
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from beta_gui import Ui_MainWindow  # importing our generated file

import sys
class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.AddButton)
    def AddButton(self,result):
        try:
            self.ui.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.ui.centralwidget)
            self.ui.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 75, 23))
            self.ui.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
            self.ui.pushButton_3.setText("buton_3")
            self.update()
            print(self.ui.pushButton_3.text())
            self.show()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        return
app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

The beta_gui.py file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'beta.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(344, 301)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 90, 101, 23))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(40, 90, 75, 23))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 344, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Button_2"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you!

Comment: Publish the module `beta_gui.py`

Comment: Hello S. Nick, thank you for your reply. I just added the code of beta_gui.py!

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
#import os
#os.system("C:\Python37\python -m PyQt5.uic.pyuic -x  beta.ui -o beta_gui.py")
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from beta_gui import Ui_MainWindow  # importing our generated file

import sys
class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.AddButton)
        self.num = 3

        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.ui.centralwidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ui.pushButton)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.ui.pushButton_2)

    def AddButton(self,result):
        button = QtWidgets.QPushButton("button {}".format(self.num))
        button.clicked.connect(lambda: print(button.text()))
        self.layout.addWidget(button)
        self.num += 1

#        try:
#        self.ui.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.ui.centralwidget)
#        self.ui.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 75, 23))
#        self.ui.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
#        self.ui.pushButton_3.setText("buton_3")
#        self.update()
#        print(self.ui.pushButton_3.text())
#        self.show()
#        except Exception as e:
#            print(e)
#        return


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

use the show method to your Widget (not the window) you want to put after the show method

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).